# Responding to reviewer concerns re: MANOVA

Tags: multivariate-analysis, sas, discriminant-analysis, manova

We conducted a study examining how individuals rate other individuals ("targets") on the basis of information about their exercise status. The IVs are rater exercise status (low, medium, high) and target exercise status (low, medium, high). The targets were rated on 30 characteristics (30 DVs).

In summary, we conducted a 3 (rater exercise status) x 3 (target exercise status) MANOVA with target exercise status and rater exercise stats as the between-subjects factors and the 30 traits as the DVs.

We found a significant main effect (Pillai's trace) for target exercise status, but no main effect for rater exercise status and no significant interaction. Wefollowed-up on the significant main effect with univariate ANOVAs for each of the 30 DVs.

Reviewer: "Remember that with a MANOVA you make your outcome measures a vector/factor and then have to see what the factor produces and what produces the factor. This is very different from the Univariate approach."

"ANOVA provides some protection for the multiple ANOVAS, but represents another view of the data and offers the (missed by the authors) opportunity to see how the components of the MANOVA contribute to the overall main effect. The lack of interactions in the MANOVA allows follow up analyses to the MANOVA that reveal the contributions to be more easily examined. Another words the MANOVA allows the authors to investigate the correlations between the measures as they form the construct that is revealed in the MANOVA and the degree to which each measure contributes to the discrimination between groups."

I'm having trouble fully understanding the reviewer's comment. I take it to mean they want a discriminate analysis (e.g. DDA)? If so, does anyone have any resources they could point me to? I'm working in SAS and am new to this technique.

Many thanks.

Comment: I must say I didn't understand the reviewer either, absolutely.

Comment: In your text, you must be mistaken: you have both ivs as between subject factors, don't you?

Comment: @ttnphns Yes, I think you're correct. Editing post.